# Acrylic enclosure for Arduino

Tags: enclosure

I've been browsing Aliexpress and eBay for decent Arduino enclusures, but I've found out they are even pricier then boards themselves.

Then I've realized that there are multiple firms that offer cheap laser cutting - I can buy 1 sq.m acrylic sheet and order cutting multiple parts of boxes at once.

Obviously I am not the first one who came up with this idea. Has anyone seen downloadable vector layouts I can use as something to start from? Thanks.

Comment: Found something here - https://www.thingiverse.com/tag:arduino_case/page:1 - but it is still far, far away from what I've imagined :(

Comment: What do you want to case exactly? If it's just the Arduino, wouldn't any project box of the right size do?

Comment: I'd like to have small box that would be used to store the completed assembly, protect it from dust and mechanical damage. I currently use small flat food containers - I drill holes for wires and then seal them with construction silicone glue. They are sturdy and cheap, but it looks ugly, they are usually 1.5-2 times larger than needed.

Answer (score 1):

Making your own is quite possible, especially if you own a router (or even better a router table). You need a V shaped 90 degree router bit, a tube of proper perspex glue and some acrylic sheet. The glue is hard to find, but plastic sign manufacturers generally will sell it. Unless you are a DIY expert, I suggest the gap filling type of glue rather than the watery product that only fills perfectly matched surfaces. Try searching Youtube on "acrylic box making". There are several videos. My first two efforts were pretty bad, but the last couple are fine, and are of course exactly the right size.

Comment: cutting and gluing aren't the issues - as I said, there are multiple firms around that will take your blueprint and cut whatever you want, for peanuts. It is vector blueprints (in CorelDraw, or DWG format, for example) I can't find. I ended with obtaining original EAGLE schematic files for Arduino and getting exact dimensions and positions for mounting holes from there. But it looks like I'll need old-fashioned caliper and ruler for stuff like LCD screens and other peripherals :(